# Adding item in array in an object with usestate replaces it instead

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-state

Looked everywhere but can't find a solution to my problem. I have a listener for when messages are being added which works but for some reason when a message gets added the array in the usestate the messages array gets replaced so there's one ever one item in there, when I add the onmModified in to it, it gets even worse... Instead of updating that value it empties the entire array...

```
  const { chatID } = route.params;

  const [values, setValues] = useState<States>({
    chat: chats[chats.findIndex((c) => c.chatID === chatID)],
    messages: [],
    isLoading: false,
    input: "",
    isSending: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    initMessages(); // Fetches previous messages which works but the listener below finds a need to replace the array instead of just adding to it... 
    
    const unsubMessages = MessagesAPI.incomming(values.chat,
      (message) => {
        console.log("onAdded: " + message?.messageID);
        setValues({ ...values, messages: [...values.messages, message!] }); // This...
      }, (message) => {
        console.log("onModified: " + message?.messageID);
        setValues({
          ...values, messages: values.messages.map((m: Message, idx: number) => {
            if (m.messageID === message!.messageID) {
              return message!;
            }
            return m;
          })
        }); // And this......
      }, (message) => {
        console.log("onRemoved: " + message?.messageID);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }, () => {
        console.log("Closed...");
      });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running this inside of a `useEffect` hook. Whenever an effect uses something that may change from one render cycle to the next (like `state` and `props` variables), it needs to be added to the dependency array. Otherwise your effect will "retain" stale variables. Be extra careful about this, especially when your effect is running just once, like yours (because of the empty `[]` dependency array).

When you listener is running, it's probably seeing a stale value of the variable `values`. As it was when you set up the listener on the `useEffect`.

So, in theory, you would need to add the `values` variable to your dependency array. And setup and remove the listener everytime that the `values` variable changes.

But from seeing what you are trying to do, it's easier to just not use the `values` variable at all, and just use the functional form of the `setState` call.

You can access the `prevState` variable, which will always be up-to-date with the previous state that you are using to update it to the new state.

Replace this:

```
setValues({ ...values, messages: [...values.messages, message!] });
```

With this:

```
setValues((prevState) => 
  ({ ...prevState, messages: [...prevState.messages, message!] })
);
```

Do the same for the other `setValues` call.

See if that works.

Comment: It didn't work same thing unfortunately. making the messages it's on hook works I know that but the the reasoning behind this was to this convert this values to a redux slice so I don't have to refetch the messages I already did yaknow.

Comment: Keep tweaking it around and you'll fix it. Very high chances your bug is related to that. Your listeners are retaining the initial value for the `values` object. Good luck.